# inserting one map into another map of a same multimap gives seg fault

Tags: c++, multimap

I have the following code declaration of `multimap`:

```
typedef std::multimap<std::string,std::string> rd;

std::multimap<std::string, rd> Rdout;
std::multimap<std::string, rd> Rdin;
```

I use the following to find two map iterators:

```
std::multimap<std::string,rd>:: iterator ot =
Rdout.find(B.getName().str()+B.getParent()->getName().str());

std::multimap<std::string,rd>:: iterator it = 
Rdin.find(B.getName().str()+B.getParent()->getName().str());
```

When I try to insert inner map of Rdin into Rdout which are of same type I get segfault

```
if(!it->second.empty())
{
    ot->second.insert(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

Appreciate your help thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried to dereference ot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!it->second.empty())
{
    ot->second.insert(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

should be

```
if(it != Rdin.end())
{
    ot->second.insert(it->second.begin(), it->second.end());
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `(it != Rdin.end())`

Comment: May as well do the same for `ot`, btw.